# Merging two data tables with two id variables and NA values

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

I would like to merge the following data tables

```
dt1 <- data.table(id = letters[1:5], day = 1, var1 = c(2,5,8,7,9), var2 = c(5,5,8,6,7), key = "id")
dt2 <- data.table(id = letters[3:7], day = 2, var1 = c(1,7,6,6,3), var2 = c(2,3,3,2,1), key = "id")
```

and the results should include for each id, each of the days. Unfortunately, some ids are not present over days.

```
id day var1 var2
a   1   2   5
a   2   NA  NA
b   1   5   5
b   2   NA  NA
c   1   8   8
c   2   1   2
d   1   7   6
d   2   7   3
```

I have tried setting `id` and `day` as keys for both `DT`. With the following lines I don't manage to get `day` 2 for a `id` as it is actually missing, and the variables are doubled (var1.x var1.y)

```
merge(dt1, dt2, by= c("id","day"), all=TRUE)
merge(dt1, dt2, by= c("day","id"), all=TRUE)
```

The `allow.cartesian` doesn't work either. Anyone has any idea/comment on how to get the final table that I need?

Comment: Are you sure you do not simply want to combine the rows? Try if `rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2))` does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(rbind(dt1, dt2), id=c('id', 'day')), 
        id+day~variable, value.var='value', drop=FALSE)
# 1:  a   1    2    5
# 2:  a   2   NA   NA
# 3:  b   1    5    5
# 4:  b   2   NA   NA
# 5:  c   1    8    8
# 6:  c   2    1    2
# 7:  d   1    7    6
# 8:  d   2    7    3
# 9:  e   1    9    7
#10:  e   2    6    3
#11:  f   1   NA   NA
#12:  f   2    6    2
#13:  g   1   NA   NA
#14:  g   2    3    1
```

Or as @BramVisser commented, replace the `rbind(dt1, dt2)` with `rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2))`

Or another approach without using `melt/dcast`

```
rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2))[, if(.N <2) .SD[c(.N, .N+1)] else .SD, id][,
    day:=replace(day, is.na(day), setdiff(1:2,na.omit(day))) , id][]
```

Or

```
setkey(rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2)), id, day)[CJ(id=unique(id), day=unique(day))]
```